# How do I determine the flow of updates in database?

Tags: update

I am pretty sure I can't make this clear enough, but I'll try my best.

Say there are tables in database.

```
Players_Basic_Info

Players_Login

Players_Net_Worth

Players_Salary

Players_Matches_History

Players_Performance
```

There is a column in Players_Performance table called WAS_GOOD. If WAS_GOOD=TRUE, salary in Players_Salary table gets updated accordingly and eventually, Players_Net_Worth table also gets updated. It was easy here because you know how the system works. But in complex and not well-documented systems you're not sure of the flow. Plus on legacy systems, the naming conventions being used are vague and meaningless thus providing little to no value for understanding.

In that case, how can I understand how the flow of updates happen in a database without hitting any update query by myself?

I was hopeful that looking at server's logs could provide some valuable input but I was disappointed to see it not being logged in server logs either.

```
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18424.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)                     16.100.47021.0+7eef34a564af48c5b0cf0d617a65fd77f06c3eb1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        15.0.19750.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.9600
```

Comment: This is unfortunately unanswerable with the minimal information provided. The answer will vary greatly depending on which database system and version is being used. And there never is a perfect way to reverse engineer the call stack regardless, but some database systems have profiling tools so that you can at least see what objects are called in which order while an update is in the middle of executing. Good naming convention of the objects obviously helps, as you noted.

Comment: The database is related to finance technology.

Comment: That doesn't help. We would need to know the name of the database product and which version, that is being used.

Comment: updated in  post

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you still haven't provided the name of the database product and its version yet, but seeing that you're using a multitude of Microsoft technologies (including SSMS), it's probably safe to assume you're using Microsoft SQL Server as your database system.

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, then there are a few ways to trace the workflow of a query:

1. [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) - "*Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL Trace for monitoring an instance of the Database Engine or Analysis Services. You can capture and save data about each event to a file or table to analyze later.*"
2. [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16) - "*The Extended Events architecture enables users to collect as much or as little data as is necessary to troubleshoot or identify a performance problem in SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Managed Instance. Extended Events is highly configurable, lightweight, and scales very well.*"
3. [SQL Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver16) - "*In SQL Trace, events are gathered if they are instances of event classes listed in the trace definition. These events can be filtered out of the trace or queued for their destination. The destination can be a file or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO), which can use the trace information in applications that manage SQL Server.*"

I personally find the Profiler the most user friendly of all of the options. But according to the docs, Microsoft might stop supporting that tool in the future.